# receiving GPG error notification each time I do sudo apt update, and sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

getting this readout while doing update, and upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done                 
W: GPG error: http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

and the same message after doing `sudo apt upgrade`, any help?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository is obsolete. It was last updated in 2013-2016. You have to disable it from Software & Updates (or `software-properties-gtk`) and then install VLC from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=vlc):

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```